# sum of all bytes in a hex file

Tags: sum, hex, byte

Can someone help me with an example? I have ZERO experience.
I have a file with the size of 128k. At the end of the file (at 1FFFC) there are 4 bytes: the first 2 are the sum of all bytes before it and the last 2 is the sum xor'ed by FFFF.
The same problem for 64k file.
I don't need anything fancy, just a way to find the sum + xor, I will manually insert them in the file.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi hi hi! Can you share what you already tried?

Comment: Hi. The only hint I found so far is this:
checksum = sum(map(ord, b))

or

checksum = sum(bytearray(b))